# resource attr/?? not found after Android Studio Update

Tags: android, gradle

So my project worked fine before the current Android Studio Update and Now I have the following error:

[image]

Here is my Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.triple.m.#####"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 22

        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.2.1'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.21'
    compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.6.5'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

What seems to b the problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Open the gradle.properties and add this:

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```